# Custom DropdownFor in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to build dropdowns automatically in my project by creating my own Html helper method that takes a "dropdown group" code and automatically builds the Html. However, it needs to do this while fully supporting the model.

My end code needs to look like this.

```
<%: Html.CodeList(m => m.state, 121) %>
```

... where "121" is the code group that returns a dictionary of key/value pairs from the database.

Here's what I have for my Html helper method so far.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString CodeList<T, TProp>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expr, int category)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> codeList = CodeManager.GetCodeList(category); //returns dictionary of key/values for the dropdown
        return html.DropDownListFor(expr, codeList, new Object()); //this line here is the problem
    }
```

I can't figure how what exactly to hand to the DropDownListFor method. I assume that I do return html.DropDownListFor() but I'm missing something obvious. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CodeList<T, TProp>(
    this HtmlHelper<T> html, 
    Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expr, 
    int category
)
{
    var codeList = CodeManager.GetCodeList(category);

    var selectList = new SelectList(
        codeList.Select(item => new SelectListItem { 
            Value = item.Key.ToString(), 
            Text = item.Value
        }), 
        "Value", 
        "Text"
    );
    return html.DropDownListFor(expr, selectList);
}
```

Remark: static methods such as `CodeManager.GetCodeList` are very bad in terms of unit testing your components in isolation.

Comment: How would you recommend that I separate out the "GetCodeList" without having to call it myself every time I want a dropdown?